# Spring Boot 1.5.6 auto reload not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, hotswap

I am working with Spring Boot application. I want to auto reload feature of spring boot so I can get java code change effect on my application but it's not working for me. Below are the details of my application:

```
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.6.RELEASE
Type: Maven
Packaging: War
IDE: STS (Spring Tool Suite)
Java Version: 1.8.0_144
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

I have added following dependency for auto reloading.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: How did you named your project? It could be similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634422/spring-boot-devtools-doesnt-want-to-reload-process-doesnt-pick-up-proper-clas).

Comment: Good hunch by @sebast26. If that's not it, it could be because its a .war project. War project are not quite as well supported / tested in STS. If you try it with a jar project and it works, you may want to file a bug report about it.